# Check Date Exist or not in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I write a sql statement into vb.net to fetch data from msaccess where date equal to patepicker control. But here syntax error.
My code given below:-

```
 Dim ct As String = "select * from add_student where _Date <= #" & dtDate1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(ct)
        cmd.Connection = con
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Note:- _Date column had Date/Time Data type in ms access database 
Please suggest me, Where is mistake

Answer (score 1):

You should always use parameters:

```
dim sqlQuery ="Select * from add_student where _Date = ?"
using conn = New OleDbConnection("connectionstring")
    conn.open()
    Using selectCmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn)
        selectCmd.Parameters.Add("_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtDate1
        using rdr = selectCmd.ExecuteReader()
            while rdr.read()

            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be that "/" is not a slash but the localized date separator.

Thus, force slashes:

```
Dim ct As String = "select * from add_student where _Date <= #" & dtDate1.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") & "#"
```

and perhaps brackets for the weird field name:

```
Dim ct As String = "select * from add_student where [_Date] <= #" & dtDate1.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") & "#"
```

Comment: I got same error :- Syntax error in query expression '_Date = #05/18/2016#'.